# Threads: How do I know which thread a method runs in?

Tags: java, multithreading, class, methods

In Java:

I have a thread that starts running in class `Xclass`. This thread calls method `a()` from class `Yclass`, and method `a()` calls method  `b()` from class `Zclass`.

Is `b()` surely running in the same thread as `a()`?

Comment: There is no method call which will magically jump to another thread.  This is actually very difficult to do and there are libraries which can make it look like this is happening but actually it is doing a lot of clever work to make this happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you start a new thread ( by calling `th.start()` ), the JVM creates a
new thread of execution and calls the `th.run()` method. Then imagine that
`run()` calls A calls B calls C calls D, etc. (A, B, C, D, etc. are methods).
All these methods A, B, C, D are executed in that same thread
(the one you called start on).

You can call `Thread.currentThread().getName()` anytime (in any of `run`, `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, etc.)
to get the name of the `th` thread which you started. Before starting `th`, you can
set a name to it (by calling `th.setName()`). I guess this answers your question.

Answer (score 5):

Unless you start any other thread on the way, invoking/calling methods will **never** start in new threads.

Easy way to check can be done by printing the output of the currently executing thread's name as such:

```
System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
```

If you think about it, should sequential invocations of methods have the ability to automatically start a new thread, it gives rise to the possibility that multiple sequential methods run concurrently. This would be highly illogical as a case may arise where one of the running methods generate the arguments for another, how can the other start without the former method completing execution.